# Getting Text from external URL via AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to get the JSON-Text-Stream from an URL (e.g. SOMEURL/ean.php?id=4001513007704). The result looks like this:

```html
{
    "product": {
        "ean_id": "4001513007704",
        "title": "Gerolsteiner Mineralwasser",
...
     },
    "success": true
}
```

As you can see these are some informations for scanned items.
I searched for implementations using URLs (--> http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_http_get ) and this example only works for the internal URL. Google and other sources leave the variable blank.

This does work. It returns the HTML-Code of the entered website:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 

<p>Today's welcome message is:</p>

<h1>{{myWelcome}}</h1>

</div>

<p>The $http service requests a page on the server, and the response is set as the value of the "myWelcome" variable.</p>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("http://www.w3schools.com/angular/default.asp")
  .then(function(response) {
      $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
  });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And this doesn't (variable is left blank). In this case i use Google but usually we would use another source!

```html
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("http://google.com/")
  .then(function(response) {
      $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
  });
});
</script>
```

I assume that it's because of the security settings from the website..

**How can i get the data from the URL? Is there any workaround?**

Thanks for any kind of help!

Comment: Already voted to close.

Answer (score 1):

`response.data` will only return something if there is a `data` object within response.

The response thatyou get when you send a request to `google.com` is this:

```
<TITLE>302 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>302 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="https://www.google.co.in/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

This is because that URL serves up an HTML, and not some JSON response.

If you do a `response.data` on this, it will be undefined because there *is* no data there. If you hit a proper end point that has JSON data, you will get your response.

For example if you change the url to `https://api.github.com/users/mralexgray/repos`, you'll see data.

Comment: Shouldn't response.data return at least the HTML Code from the Website? It shouldn't be blank..

Comment: response would. response.data wouldn't. Because this is not JSON, and you can't use the dot notation

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you are not defining the angular module to be included in the html.
Try running the above code in w3 schools with the link http://google.com/ in the site as shown

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 

<p>Today's welcome message is:</p>

<h1>{{myWelcome}}</h1>

</div>

<p>The $http service requests a page on the server, and the response is set as the value of the "myWelcome" variable.</p>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("http://google.com/")
  .then(function(response) {
      $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
  });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Hey! Sorry, but i don't get what you are trying to tell me. Your screenshot leaves the space blank as well! Can you explain what you mean in concrete?

Comment: Screenshot describes tha twhen i hit google.com it responds success and then the message is printed,meaning it works